# PHP Remote file streaming with Resume Support

Tags: php, file, download, resume

Firstly, I am aware of similar question being asked before.

The subject pretty much explains the question but still,

the file is hosted on another server, the user will download file via my script, streamed to him...

But the problem is user can't resume it once paused...any solutions?

Answer (score 17):

You can try implementing your own download script using `Accept-Ranges` and `Content-Range` here is a prof of concept :

```
set_time_limit(0);
$download = new ResumeDownload("word.dir.txt", 50000); //delay about in microsecs 
$download->process();
```

**Using Internet Download Manager**

**Start**

[image: Start]

**Paused**

[image: Paused]

**Paused State**

[image: Paused State]

**Resume**

[image: Resume]

**Finished**

[image]

**Class Used**

```
class ResumeDownload {
    private $file;
    private $name;
    private $boundary;
    private $delay = 0;
    private $size = 0;

    function __construct($file, $delay = 0) {
        if (! is_file($file)) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
            die("<h3>File Not Found</h3>");
        }

        $this->size = filesize($file);
        $this->file = fopen($file, "r");
        $this->boundary = md5($file);
        $this->delay = $delay;
        $this->name = basename($file);
    }

    public function process() {
        $ranges = NULL;
        $t = 0;
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) && $range = stristr(trim($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']), 'bytes=')) {
            $range = substr($range, 6);
            $ranges = explode(',', $range);
            $t = count($ranges);
        }

        header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header(sprintf('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="%s"', $this->name));

        if ($t > 0) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial content");
            $t === 1 ? $this->pushSingle($range) : $this->pushMulti($ranges);
        } else {
            header("Content-Length: " . $this->size);
            $this->readFile();
        }

        flush();
    }

    private function pushSingle($range) {
        $start = $end = 0;
        $this->getRange($range, $start, $end);
        header("Content-Length: " . ($end - $start + 1));
        header(sprintf("Content-Range: bytes %d-%d/%d", $start, $end, $this->size));
        fseek($this->file, $start);
        $this->readBuffer($end - $start + 1);
        $this->readFile();
    }

    private function pushMulti($ranges) {
        $length = $start = $end = 0;
        $output = "";

        $tl = "Content-type: application/octet-stream\r\n";
        $formatRange = "Content-range: bytes %d-%d/%d\r\n\r\n";

        foreach ( $ranges as $range ) {
            $this->getRange($range, $start, $end);
            $length += strlen("\r\n--$this->boundary\r\n");
            $length += strlen($tl);
            $length += strlen(sprintf($formatRange, $start, $end, $this->size));
            $length += $end - $start + 1;
        }
        $length += strlen("\r\n--$this->boundary--\r\n");
        header("Content-Length: $length");
        header("Content-Type: multipart/x-byteranges; boundary=$this->boundary");
        foreach ( $ranges as $range ) {
            $this->getRange($range, $start, $end);
            echo "\r\n--$this->boundary\r\n";
            echo $tl;
            echo sprintf($formatRange, $start, $end, $this->size);
            fseek($this->file, $start);
            $this->readBuffer($end - $start + 1);
        }
        echo "\r\n--$this->boundary--\r\n";
    }

    private function getRange($range, &$start, &$end) {
        list($start, $end) = explode('-', $range);

        $fileSize = $this->size;
        if ($start == '') {
            $tmp = $end;
            $end = $fileSize - 1;
            $start = $fileSize - $tmp;
            if ($start < 0)
                $start = 0;
        } else {
            if ($end == '' || $end > $fileSize - 1)
                $end = $fileSize - 1;
        }

        if ($start > $end) {
            header("Status: 416 Requested range not satisfiable");
            header("Content-Range: */" . $fileSize);
            exit();
        }

        return array(
                $start,
                $end
        );
    }

    private function readFile() {
        while ( ! feof($this->file) ) {
            echo fgets($this->file);
            flush();
            usleep($this->delay);
        }
    }

    private function readBuffer($bytes, $size = 1024) {
        $bytesLeft = $bytes;
        while ( $bytesLeft > 0 && ! feof($this->file) ) {
            $bytesLeft > $size ? $bytesRead = $size : $bytesRead = $bytesLeft;
            $bytesLeft -= $bytesRead;
            echo fread($this->file, $bytesRead);
            flush();
            usleep($this->delay);
        }
    }
}
```

[File Used](http://ge.tt/66eyMJd/v/0?c)

Comment: realy greate job 1+

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP to serve the file, you have to implement all resuming logic yourself.

You'll have to send [Accept-Ranges](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5) and [respond appropriately](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16) to [Ranges](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.12).

That's a chunk of work. It might be easier to use `mod_proxy`.

Answer (score 1):

What's the purpose of this? hiding urls only or just allowing members to download?

The way you described it, it's a bit tricky ...

1. The remote server your script will download from should support resuming downloads.
2. Your php script should check for 'Accept-Range' header & pass it through to the remote server (using sockets is your best option I guess) so your script is actually acting as a proxy.