# How to Implement Resumable Download in Silex

Tags: symfony, silex

In [silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#sending-a-file) I can do this to force-download a file:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;

$app = new Silex\Application();

// Url can be http://pathtomysilexapp.com/download
$app->get('/download', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    $file = '/path/to/download.zip';

    if( !file_exists($file) ){
        return new Response('File not found.', 404);
    }

    return $app->sendFile($file)->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, 'download.zip');
});

$app->run();
```

This works well for smaller files. However my use case requires downloading a big that can be paused/resumed by a download manager.

There is an example about file [streaming](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#streaming) but it doesn't seem to be what I am looking for. Has somebody done this before? I could just use the [answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894299/php-remote-file-streaming-with-resume-support) and be done with it. But it would be nice if there is a silexy way of doing this.

Comment: Silex HTTP's core is based on Symphony components, you should add the [tag:symfony] to extend the number of reader of your question

Comment: I found something (not written with Symfony Components/Silex) but it seems to work .. https://gist.github.com/kosinix/4cf0d432638817888149

Comment: @ohartl - I wrote that gist :-)

Comment: that's kinda funny :)

Answer (score 0):

Implementing it is quite trivial if you have a the file on the drive. It is like paginating records from a table.

Read the headers, open the file, seek to the desired position and read the the size requested.

You only need to know a little bit about the headers from the request & response.

Does the server accept ranges:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

HTTP 206 status for content ranges:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206

Info about the content range headers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Range